# SHA256 digest differs between array initializer and string

Tags: c, hash, sha256

I use the sha256 function of Microchip ATECC508A security chip. My code looks like this:

```
int main(void) {
    uint8_t message[32] = {0}; // Method 1
    //uint8_t message[32] = "00000000000000000000000000000000"; // Method 2
    foobar(message, sizeof(message));
}

void foobar(uint8_t *message, int length) {
    uint8_t digest[32];
    sha256(message, length, digest);
    // printf statements for calculated hashes ...
}
```

> Method 1: 66687AADF862BD776C8FC18B8E9F8E20089714856EE233B3902A591D0D5F2925
>
> Method 2: 84E0C0EAFAA95A34C293F278AC52E45CE537BAB5E752A00E6959A13AE103B65A

Method 2 delievers the corresponding hash I expect for 32 zeros, but when I use the static array initializer in method 1, the hash is wrong and I don't know why. I've checked the resulting sha256 hashes [here](https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha256-hash-generator/).

I would appreciate any help, thank you very much.

EDIT:

I was able to to initialize the whole array with characters of zeros with:

`uint8_t message[32] = { [0 ... 31] = '0'}`.

This only works on gcc compilers.

Comment: So maybe it is designed to work with ASCII. Surely you know the difference between integers and strings?

Comment: Can you paste a link in your answer to the documentation for the `sha256()` function you're using?

Comment: @Lundin Problem solved, was not my day, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the second case, the array is not filled with the number 0 but is filled with the character `'0'`.

In ASCII, the encoding for `'0'` is 48, so assuming your system uses ASCII then every element of your array has the value 48.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm new in c programming and my main problem was that I thought the array initializer would fill **all** values with the defined value in brackets, but it only affects the first one and all other positions are initialized with zero. The other problem was the ascii representation, thanks!